# RewriteRule not working for Wordpress category

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a RewriteRule for redirecting traffic after I have changed the name of some categories in Wordpress.

The old URL looked like this…

```
http://www.example.com/category/fitness/
```

I want it to redirect to…

```
http://www.example.com/category/health-and-lifestyle/
```

I can get it to work using the following rule, but it only ever rewrites the main category, and doesn't do the same for paginated pages .i.e  fitness/page/2/, fitness/page/3/ etc

```
RewriteRule category/fitness/*? category/health-and-lifestyle/ [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone help me get this working so that it makes the following…

```
http://www.example.com/category/fitness/
http://www.example.com/category/fitness/page/2/
http://www.example.com/category/fitness/page/3/
```

rewrite to…

```
http://www.example.com/category/health-and-lifestyle/
http://www.example.com/category/health-and-lifestyle/page/2/
http://www.example.com/category/health-and-lifestyle/page/3/
```

Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect regex in `category/fitness/*?`.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^category/fitness/(.*)$ category/health-and-lifestyle/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: You need round brackets either side of `.*`, or it won't work

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: Thanks so much, yes it was a typo. I fixed.

Comment: Yes sure. Your regex: `category/fitness/*?` was problematic. It was not matching any text after `category/fitness` OR `category/fitness/`